# How to make clothing and body move as one?

Tags: armature

I'm still new to Blender and am playing around with models that I've gotten from models-resource. This is what I have now: The cat body and the clothing are 2 separate armatures. I'm trying to adjust the pose of the model but I'm not able to move the clothing and body as one. Joining the armatures doesn't work.

[image: Workspace]

This is what I get after joining the armatures, the body and clothing still acts as 2 different objects! After joining, the clothing's mesh and armature became separated too!

[image: After Joining]

Comment: hello, yes you should join the armatures, make sure that the bones have different names

Comment: @moonboots I've tried and it doesn't work... please help T_T

Comment: hello, please share your file (delete the parts you don't want to share): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots here! https://pasteall.org/blend/bf10949c9af94647b2782816af8736b7

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should :

- Apply the rotation of the armature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Rotation*)
- Get rid of the part of the mesh you don’t need, for example the arms, as you have sleeves, but keep everything if needed (but you’ll have to do more corrections after parenting), and anyway keep a unchanged version somewhere.
- Join all the objects together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
- Unparent the object with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear and Keep Transformation*
- Parent *With Automatic Weight*, make the needed corrections in *Weight Paint* mode or in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups* list and with the *Assign* button